# AngularJS ui.grid exporter fail to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am developing a data backend using AngularJS ui.grid. But it seems that it cannot load ui.grid.exporter module when I attempted to load following the tutorial from http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data.

HTML

```
<div class="grid" ui-grid="{data: roiTableData, columnDefs: roiCols, enableGridMenu: true, exporterCsvFilename: 'myFile.csv', enableSelectAll: true, onRegisterApi: gridApiFunc}" ui-grid-exporter></div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.grid.exporter',
    'ui.grid.pinning',
    'ui.grid.resizeColumns'
]).constroller(...);
```

The export function doesn't show on the grid menu after I refresh the page.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker showing the issue? Furthermore it looks like you have a typo in your js code: constroller instead of controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to include the uiGridExporterService as a dependency for the controller which gets loaded.

```
angular.module('my-app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.exporter'])
.controller('myController', function(uiGridExporterService){
    console.log('successfully loaded myController and uiGridExporterService');
});
```

Comment: How did you include it?